# add first element a default item to arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist, autocompletetextview

here i have an array list

```
  ArrayList<String> arrlist = new ArrayList<String>();
while (cursors.moveToNext()) {
            arrlist.add((cursors.getString(cursors.getColumnIndex("location"))));
            adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getBaseContext(),
                    R.layout.drop_list_item,
                    arrlist);

            autocompletetextview.setAdapter(adapter1);

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    prepareMyList();
}

private void prepareMyList() {
    ArrayList<String> arrlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    String selectQuerys = "select distinct location from tb_user where location like '%"+autoservice.getText().toString()+"%'";
    SQLiteDatabase dbs = sq.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursors = dbs.rawQuery(selectQuerys, null);

    while (cursors.moveToNext()) {
        arrlist.add((cursors.getString(cursors.getColumnIndex("location"))));
        adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getBaseContext(),
                R.layout.drop_list_item,
                arrlist);

        autoservice.setAdapter(adapter1);

    }
}
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

}
```

if i type 'a' in autocomplete textview all items stating with 'a' will come as suggestions, similarly for all other letters
 my need is i need a default item "automatic"  at first of suggestion eventhough we type any letter in autocomplete textview

Comment: Do you mean text hint on the list view?

Comment: So you want a default item to show when no other items show in the list? Or do you always want to have the same first item regardless of the search? Some clarification would be great

Comment: am using a location list but my first suggestion must always be "automatically detect"

Comment: @windedmoose always want to have the same first item regardless of the search

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to add the automatically detected location before you loop through the cursor. Earlier on, I'm assuming in `onCreate`, it would be:

```
ArrayList<String> arrlist = new ArrayList<String>();
arrlist.add("automatically detect");
while (cursors.moveToNext()) { //...
```

Then in `prepareMyList`:

```
private void prepareMyList() {
  ArrayList<String> arrlist = new ArrayList<String>();
  arrlist.add("automatically detect");
  String selectQuerys = //...
```

This should add "automatically detect" as the first item initially and when you search.

**Note**: You should consider moving some of your code out of your while loop to make it more efficient (and likely less buggy). You don't need to create a new `ArrayAdapter` or set the adapter every time through the loop. You can just do this one time after the loop ends. All you need in your loops is:

```
while (cursors.moveToNext()) {
    arrlist.add((cursors.getString(cursors.getColumnIndex("location"))));
}
adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getBaseContext(),
            R.layout.drop_list_item,
            arrlist);
autoservice.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

Comment: in this case when we type 'b' in autocompletetextview it wont show "automatically detect", we should type a to see it

Comment: Could you post the code that does the search and updates the adapter? It sounds like that is where the actual code change needs to go.

Comment: Ok great, I edited my answer based on your updated code.

Comment: in on create i have not created array

Comment: am using a location list but my first suggestion must always be "automatically detect". now when i press a its ok but for all other letters it wont show

Comment: i had done this arrlist.add((cursors.getString(cursors.getColumnIndex("location"))));
 but still same problem

Comment: Did you add `arrlist.add("automatically detect");` in `prepareMyList()` before the while loop?

Comment: ya but still like this

Comment: i think its autocompletetextview's speciality for sorting based on index, because if we give complete array also it gives us result based on input only

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> arrlist = new ArrayList<String>();
arrlist.add("Default element");
```

Comment: i think its autocompletetextview's speciality for sorting based on index, because if we give complete array also it gives us result based on input only